# Mysql referencing and select into

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I need some help with some tsql to mysql translation :).

```
select id,
       title,
       release_date, 
       imdb_id, 
       spoken_languages, 
       runtime
  into [DatabaseDestination].dbo.tableDestination
  from [DatabaseSource].dbo.tableSource;

ALTER TABLE [DatabaseDestination].dbo.tableDestination;
ALTER COLUMN id float NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE [DatabaseDestination].dbo.tableDestination add primary key (id);
```

How do you do this generic referencing or navigation into mysql **[DatabaseDestination].dbo.dMovie_details**, and how do you translate the code from above?

Comment: insert into destination select from source

Comment: Are you intending to run this solely in mysql or are you attempting to read from sql server and write to mysql?

Comment: i'm going to read from sql and write to mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO db2.tableDestination (id, title, release_date, imdb_id, spoken_languages,
    runtime)
SELECT id, title, release_date, imdb_id, spoken_languages, runtime
FROM db1.tableSource;
```

It is general good practice to always specify the columns into which you intend to insert, though MySQL does not require it.  I don't actually know the names of the columns in the destination table, so I made an educated guess and assumed they are the same as the column names in the source table.

For your other steps, you should handle the schema issues when you create the destination table in MySQL.

Comment: thank you @tim, what about this navigation that I was able to do in tsql: [DatabaseDestination].dbo.tableDestination, how do I secify that in mysql?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do that, assuming both tables are in the same database.  Just select the database you want to use with `USE mydb`.

Comment: they are in diffrent databases

Comment: Then just preface the table name by the database name, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Insert into --- select from and for table navigation write like DatabaseDestination.tableDestination

```
insert into DatabaseDestination.tableDestination(id, title,release_date, imdb_id, spoken_languages, runtime)
      select id, title,release_date, imdb_id, spoken_languages, runtime from DatabaseSource.tableSource;

ALTER TABLE DatabaseDestination.tableDestination
ALTER COLUMN id float NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE DatabaseDestination.tableDestination add primary key (id);
```